# Переработка JSON

Tags: javascript, json, zabbix

Есть JSON, нужно переделать его через JavaScript.

То, что имеем:

```
[
   {
      "{#SNMPINDEX}":"8.23.53.3.230.144",
      "{#BSNAPNAME}":"NEW1",
      "{#BSNAPOPERATIONSTATUS}":"1",
      "{#BSNAPMODEL}":"AIR",
      "{#BSNAPSERIALNUMBER}":"34563456",
      "{#BSNAPIPADDRESS}":"192.168.1.3"
   },
   {
      "{#SNMPINDEX}":"8.23.53.3.230.144.1",
      "{#CLCCDPAPCACHENEIGHNAME}":"switch1",
      "{#CLCCDPAPCACHENEIGHADDRESS}":"0A 0A 0A 0A ",
      "{#CLCCDPAPCACHENEIGHINTERFACE}":"Fa0/4"
   }
]
```

Что хотелось бы получить:

```
[
   {
      "{#SNMPINDEX}":"8.23.53.3.230.144",
      "{#BSNAPNAME}":"NEW1",
      "{#BSNAPOPERATIONSTATUS}":"1",
      "{#BSNAPMODEL}":"AIR",
      "{#BSNAPSERIALNUMBER}":"34563456",
      "{#BSNAPIPADDRESS}":"192.168.1.3"
      "{#CLCCDPAPCACHENEIGHNAME}":"switch1",
      "{#CLCCDPAPCACHENEIGHADDRESS}":"0A 0A 0A 0A ",
      "{#CLCCDPAPCACHENEIGHINTERFACE}":"Fa0/4"
   }
]
```

Получается, что SNMPINDEX одинаковый, за исключением единицы в самом конце.

Comment: Уточните всё-таки, что же делать, если есть совпадающие ключи в объектах. По вашему примеру выходит, что приоритет у первого объекта, то есть значения одинаковых ключей нельзя перезаписывать, все последующие игнорируются, верно?

Comment: Совпадающих ключей нет, всё верно. Ну и соответственно обектов разное количество.

Comment: Но в примере есть совпадающий ключ — "{#SNMPINDEX}", с разным значением.

Comment: Ой, извиняюсь, да, есть(немного не понял, так как опыта маловато). Нужно соеденить два обекта, сравнив SNMPINDEX, ключи одинаковые и значения тоже, за исключением .1 на конце. После соединения, SNMPINDEX с .1 удалить. В самом JSON, объектов много, но они парны, то есть если есть SNMPINDEX 8.23.53.3.230.144, значит есть такой же с 8.23.53.3.230.144.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```js
const data1 = [
   {
      "{#SNMPINDEX}":"8.23.53.3.230.144",
      "{#BSNAPNAME}":"NEW1",
      "{#BSNAPOPERATIONSTATUS}":"1",
      "{#BSNAPMODEL}":"AIR",
      "{#BSNAPSERIALNUMBER}":"34563456",
      "{#BSNAPIPADDRESS}":"192.168.1.3"
   },
   {
      "{#SNMPINDEX}":"8.23.53.3.230.144.1",
      "{#CLCCDPAPCACHENEIGHNAME}":"switch1",
      "{#CLCCDPAPCACHENEIGHADDRESS}":"0A 0A 0A 0A ",
      "{#CLCCDPAPCACHENEIGHINTERFACE}":"Fa0/4"
   }
];

const temp = {};

for (const entry of data1) {
  const SNMPINDEX = entry["{#SNMPINDEX}"].replace(/^(\d+(?:\.\d+){5})\.1$/, '$1');

  if (!temp[SNMPINDEX]) {
    temp[SNMPINDEX] = Object.assign({}, entry, { "{#SNMPINDEX}": SNMPINDEX });
  } else {
    Object.assign(temp[SNMPINDEX], entry, { "{#SNMPINDEX}": SNMPINDEX });
  }
}

const data2 = Object.values(temp);

console.log(data2);
```

Вариант вроде бы совместимый с duktape:

```js
const data1 = [
   {
      "{#SNMPINDEX}":"8.23.53.3.230.144",
      "{#BSNAPNAME}":"NEW1",
      "{#BSNAPOPERATIONSTATUS}":"1",
      "{#BSNAPMODEL}":"AIR",
      "{#BSNAPSERIALNUMBER}":"34563456",
      "{#BSNAPIPADDRESS}":"192.168.1.3"
   },
   {
      "{#SNMPINDEX}":"8.23.53.3.230.144.1",
      "{#CLCCDPAPCACHENEIGHNAME}":"switch1",
      "{#CLCCDPAPCACHENEIGHADDRESS}":"0A 0A 0A 0A ",
      "{#CLCCDPAPCACHENEIGHINTERFACE}":"Fa0/4"
   }
];

const temp = {};

for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
  const entry = data1[i];
  const SNMPINDEX = entry["{#SNMPINDEX}"].replace(/^(\d+(?:\.\d+){5})\.1$/, '$1');

  if (!temp[SNMPINDEX]) {
    temp[SNMPINDEX] = Object.assign({}, entry, { "{#SNMPINDEX}": SNMPINDEX });
  } else {
    Object.assign(temp[SNMPINDEX], entry, { "{#SNMPINDEX}": SNMPINDEX });
  }
}

const data2 = Object.keys(temp).map(function (key) { return temp[key]; });

console.log(data2);
```

Comment: Я вставляю код в JavaScript online, всё отрабатывает как нужно, но когда я вставляю скрипт в предобработку Zabbix JavaScript, то ругается на line 4. Возможно ему не нравится regexp(но это не точно). В zabbix JavaScript реализован при помощи Duktape, может ли это как-то повлиять на синтаксис?

Comment: У меня нет опыта с этими инструментами, но судя по https://duktape.org/, так сразу не поймёшь, какой объём современного JS там поддерживается. Есть какие-то объяснения в тексте ошибки, что именно не нравится?

Comment: Неа, только line4, и всё. Вот разбираюсь)

Comment: Вот, что конкретно пишет: SyntaxError: parse error (line 4)

Comment: Я попробовал менять код в сторону старого JS, пока https://duktape.org/dukweb.html не перестал выдавать ошибки. Попробуйте второй вариант в ответе.

Comment: Во втором варианте ещё больше ошибок:    TypeError: cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at [anon] (duktape.c:57260) internal
    at [anon] (function:6) preventsyield

Comment: Тогда я сдаюсь. Наверное, вам стоит создать новый вопрос, где подробно описать, какие сервисы и инструменты используются, добавить метку zabbix, вдруг найдутся люди, которые хорошо в этом разбираются.

Comment: Я вставляю первый Ваш код, и он оборачивается в функцию вот как это выглядит                                                 function (value) {

const data1 = value;
const temp = {};

for (const entry of data1) {
  const SNMPINDEX = entry["{#SNMPINDEX}"].replace(/^(\d+(?:\.\d+){5})\.1$/, '$1');

  if (!temp[SNMPINDEX]) {
    temp[SNMPINDEX] = Object.assign({}, entry, { "{#SNMPINDEX}": SNMPINDEX });
  } else {
    Object.assign(temp[SNMPINDEX], entry, { "{#SNMPINDEX}": SNMPINDEX });
  }
}

const data2 = Object.values(temp);

return(data2);
}

Comment: К сожалению, даже с этой оболочкой я не могу понять, откуда может взяться ошибка `cannot read property 'replace' of undefined ...`

Comment: Разве что в массиве есть объекты, в которых нет ключа "{#SNMPINDEX}"

Comment: Для теста, использую массив, который предоставил Вам.

Comment: Тогда тем более не понимаю. Простите)

Comment: Да ничего страшно, всё равно огромное спасибо!)

Comment: Кстати, если заменить "const data1 = [my JSON]" на "const data1 = JSON.parse(value);", то ошибок никаких нет, единственное, на выходе получаю ---> [object Object]

Comment: Нашёл решение! Заменил первую и последнюю Вашу строку первого кода на var data1 = JSON.parse(value);
return JSON.stringify(data2);

Comment: Ура)............